# comparing element using XSLT dynamically

Tags: xslt

I have XML document something like below.

```
<root>
    <Book>
        <Book_title/>
        <author_name/>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Book_title/>
        <author_name/>
    </Book>
    <author_details>
        <author_name/>
        <author_DOB/>
    <author_details/>
</root>
```

So can we compare Book/author_name with author_details/author_name dynamically with XSLT ...??

Comment: So what is the result you want when you say you want to compare the elements?

Comment: Something like below
---------------------------
<Book>
        <Book_title/>
        <author_name/>
        <author_DOB/>
</Book>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a key

```
<xsl:key name="author" match="author_details" use="autor_name"/>
```

then write a template for

```
<xsl:template match="Book/author_name">
  <xsl:copy-of select=". | key('author', .)/author_DOB"/>
</xsl:template>
```

handle `root` and `Book` by the identity transformation (e.g. `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` in XSLT 3) and add an empty

```
<xsl:template match="author_details"/>
```

to prevent copying/outputting those elements.